# Как найти похожую фотографию?

Tags: графика, дизайн

Имеется изображение, необходимо найти похожее, только со смартфоном.
В приоритете подобный градиент и стилистика изображение (полуиконка, полу-3D).
По каким запросам искать изображение, чтобы найти подобное?
Пытался сделать поиск по фото, разным запросам не находит.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&biw=1920&bih=969&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=LiooXoWPIsmMrwTP-57ICQ&q=+phone+display&oq=+phone+display&gs_l=img.3..0j0i7i30l9.8805.8805..8991...0.0..0.85.160.2......0....1..gws-wiz-img.P_1NkTrgQxM&ved=0ahUKEwiF3pPthZfnAhVJxosKHc-9B5kQ4dUDCAc&uact=5

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что  не по теме

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы уже совсем обленились. Не можете найти? Значит берите и рисуйте!

Вот вам нарисовал на скорую руку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: введите сюда описание изображения]